# Mithril component not updating when route changes

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application, mithril.js

I am creating my personal website/blog as a a single page application using Mithril.js. All pages and blog posts on my website are rendered using `Page` and `Post` components, and the correct page is loaded based on the `:slug` in the URL.

The problem I have is that **whenever I try and switch between pages, the content of the page does not update**. Switching between *pages and posts* works because I am alternating between `Page` and `Post` components. But when I try and use the same component twice in a row, going from *page to page*, it doesn't update the webpage.

```
m.route(document.body, '/', {
  // `Home` is a wrapper around `Page`
  // so I can route to `/` instead of `/home`
  '/': Home,
  '/:slug': Page,
  '/blog/:slug': Post
});
```

```
const Home = {
  view() {
    return m(Page, { slug: 'home' });
  }
};
```

Here is the `Page` component (the `Post` component is very similar). Both components render correctly.

```
const Page = {
  content: {},
  oninit(vnode) {
    m.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'content.json',
    }).then((response) => {
      Page.content = response.pages[vnode.attrs.slug];
    });
  },
  view() {
    if (Page.content) {
      return [
        m('#content', m.trust(Page.content.body))
      ];
    }
  }
};
```

Why isn't Mithril recognizing that the slug changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs page for `m.route`](http://mithril.js.org/route.html#key-parameter) has a solution for you.

> When a user navigates from a parameterized route to the same route with a different parameter (e.g. going from `/page/1` to `/page/2` given a route `/page/:id`, the component would not be recreated from scratch since both routes resolve to the same component, and thus result in a virtual dom in-place diff. This has the side-effect of triggering the `onupdate` hook, rather than `oninit`/`oncreate`. However, it's relatively common for a developer to want to synchronize the recreation of the component to the route change event.

Comment: Thank you! I just changed `:slug` to `:key` and now it works! :)